# Create a new BitBucket repository for existing files from Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket

I have files that I want to add to a new repository on BitBucket. How can I do this using a command line from Ubuntu ?

An alternative would be to create the repository first from the BitBucket website but I don't know how to clone a repository into a non-empty directory.

Comment: Once you've created the repository in bitbucket with the web interface, you'll have the command to type. Basically, you can add the remote bitbucket repository to your local one and push.

Comment: You do not need to do a clone anyway. This is the complete set of steps to follow, to do what you want. Hope this would be useful to anybody. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/07/create-git-bitbucket-repository-from.html?view=sidebar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More detail on [Bruce's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045228/create-a-new-bitbucket-repository-for-existing-files-from-ubuntu#comment29854091_20045228):

When you create a repo at BitBucket, you are offered two links:

- "I'm starting from scratch"
- "I have an existing project to push up"

Click on the 2nd, and you will be given the commands to run in your local repo.  These would look like:

```
> cd /path/to/my/repo
> git remote add origin https://me@bitbucket.org/me/test.git
> git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
> git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

Comment: When I run the git remote add origin command, I get the error message: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: @matdev:  Did you run "git init" in your local repo?

Comment: Indeed, it worked after running the "git init" command. Thank you so much !

Comment: This doesn't work as you should git add . and then commit before pushing. Error as "No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to '/work/fun/git_experiments/bare'" 
would show up.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do a clone anyway. And also the accepted answer is not correct. You need to do a `git add .` and then `git commit` before pushing.

This is the complete set of steps to follow, to do what you want: 
[Create a git BitBucket/ Github repository from already locally existing project  - samranga.blogspot.com](http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/07/create-git-bitbucket-repository-from.html)