# BitBucket creating a local repo and cloning it into BitBucket via gitCMD

Tags: git, bitbucket

I know this is such a rookie question. But I'm just starting out with Version Control (BitBucket in this case) and Git.

How do I:
1) Create a git repository locally.
2) Add files to the git repo. (Do they go inside the .git folder?)
3) Clone the repo to my BitBucket account.

**I don't want to use SourceTree**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a new BitBucket repository for existing files from Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045228/create-a-new-bitbucket-repository-for-existing-files-from-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a [`git init`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init) in the root folder where your files *already* are.
See "[Setting up a repository](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository)" (the `git init` part).

From there, you can add and commit.

But you also need to [create a new empty repository on BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-repositories-776639815.html).

In the previous root folder, you can then `git remote add origin /url/new/bitbucket/repo`.
Finally: `git push -u origin master`.

Comment: Thanks, although the problem I am having now is that after making additional changes to the repo, it won't properly push my changes. I get errors like: `fatal: remote origin already exists.` This is me following the **My code is ready to be pushed** on the link you sent

Comment: @JettCallard In that link, you should not repeat the git remote add step: once the remote is declared, you can use it. A simple `git push` is enough

Comment: do you know why bitbucket needs you to create the empty repo first? GitHub allows you to create the repo locally and then just push it to remote.

Comment: @Helen True, that is a feature that only GitHub supports. That being said, you can [create a Bitbucket repository through its API](https://medium.com/graymatrix/how-to-create-a-bitbucket-repository-using-bitbucket-api-2d6084dab0c).